# Push Notification queries

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, apple-push-notifications

I hope someone can help me with the following.
My app is in app store and its not receiving any push notification and my  Production Push SSL Certificate got expire yesteday only.
Do  i need to generate the new Production Push SSL Certificate and put on server.

Please help me on these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to fetch a renewed push certificate for your application from the Apple Developer Center. After that you have to put it on your server (adjust the password,...) and then your server should be able to send messages again.